# ¿Cómo oculto una animación inicial al momento de cargar la página css (Sin javascript)?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Lo que estoy haciendo es un menú con una animación de entrada y salida pero el problema aquí es que la animación de salida (sin hover) aparece cuando carga el sitio por lo cual le coloque un div la propiedad visibility hidden para que el item de la lista al activar el hover, aparecerá el submenú pero al quitar el cursor, entonces cómo hago para que esa animación no se muestre cuando cargue la página pero que esta siga apareciendo cuando pierdo el hover, en otras palabras, que al cargar la página no me aparezca la animación de salida pero cuando haga hover en el item de la lista aparezca la animación de entrada y al quitar el hover que aparezca la animación de salida.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; }
header { width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #1427d3; }
.menu { width: 100%; height: 50px; display: flex; }
.menu ul { margin: auto; display: flex; }
.menu li { list-style: none; padding: 16px 20px; transition: background-color .8s ease; }
.menu li:hover { background-color: rgba(45, 63, 221, 0.836); transition: background-color .8s ease; color: white; cursor: pointer; }
.menu ul li ul { visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; flex-direction: column; background-color: #ce8f1a; margin-top: 16px; transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0); transition: all 1.5s; box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.452); }
.menu ul li ul li:hover { background-color: #ffa704; }
.menu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible; overflow: visible; transform: rotateY(0) scale(1); transition: all 1.5s; }.menu ul li ul::before { content: ''; width: 0; height: 0; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 8px solid #ce8f1a; margin-top: -8px; margin-left: 20px; position: absolute; }
.menu ul li ul li ul li { position: relative; }
.menu ul li ul li ul { right: -90px; top: 35px; background-color: #5de61e; }
.menu ul li ul li ul li:hover { background-color: #74ff34; }
.menu ul li ul li:hover > ul { transform: rotate(0) scale(1); }
.menu ul li ul li ul::before { position: absolute; border-bottom: 8px solid #5de61e; margin-top: 14px; margin-left: -14px; transform: rotate(-90deg); }
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Inicio</li>
            <li>
                Productos
                <ul>
                    <li>Computadoras</li>
                    <li>
                        Celulares
                        <ul>
                            <li>Samsung</li>
                            <li>Motorola</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contacto</li>
            <li>Acerca de</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Aunque en el ejemplo del snippet no se aprecia bien pero cargandolo en un archivo local si se nota la animación de salida sin haber activado el hover al cargar la página... lo otro que me gustaría hacer es que el triángulo que aparece al lado indicando a que item del menú esta apuntando, quiero que cambie de color igual al primer item de submenú cuando se hace hover, pensaba hacerlo así

`.menu ul li ul li ul::before li:first-child:hover { border-bottom: 8px solid #74ff34; }`

Pero note que esto se realiza al último tag referenciado en la línea (disculpen la pobre terminología) y no lo aplica al "ul::before" como lo necesito y no se como hacerlo.